# How to run SCORM module in moodle website?

Tags: module, moodle, scorm, lms

I am developing a Moodle website for LMS and I have uploaded module course, but SCORM package is not running. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you want help with this, you're going to have to provide a lot more detail, because SCORM packages generally get added to a course and then work as expected. What have you tried doing? What happened? Were any errors displayed? Does your browser developer console show any errors? If you turn Debugging on for the Moodle site, do you see any errors? Can you post a link to the SCORM package (someone might have time to download it at try it themselves)?

Comment: Hi @davasmith Thank you for reply I am getting error like                                                
    Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.